# jQuery UI makes jQuery easing redundant

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

This is a very basic question - but I couldnt find the answer out there.

Im having the full jquery UI already included in my project - now another script needs the jquery easing plugin.

Do I still need to include that as well, or is this redundant because of jQuery UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery UI contains the easing effect, so you should not need to add any other dependencies.  See: http://jqueryui.com/effect/

Comment: Thanks, I wasnt quite sure.